# Core v0.3.24 link

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm looking for Core v0.3.24 to test something. I searched for it but couldn't find it.

Do you know where can I download Core v0.3.24 binary for macOS (not the source code)?

Comment: Downloading bitcoin binaries (or source) from untrusted sources is extremely inadvisable. Even old versions. Even for testing. I'm not sure about policy here, but I would delete any link to a binary anyone would post here (except on bitcoin.org itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Download instructions

You can download it [here as a tar.gz](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/archive/v0.3.24.tar.gz) and [here as a zip file](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/archive/v0.3.24.zip). But be aware that v0.3.24 is very old!

You can find all releases [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases).

## Build Instructions

(Assuming you have the OS X developer tools installed)

In a terminal, go to your download folder:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
```

Decompress it:

```
tar -xvf bitcoin-0.3.24.tar.gz
```

Change to the source directory:

```
cd bitcoin-0.3.24/src/
```

Run the makefile:

```
make -f makefile.osx all
```

If you have the proper dependencies installed (you need `libboost`, `libssl`, and `libcrypto`, which can easily be installed with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)) and the build succeeds, the executables `bitcoin`, `bitcoind`, and `test_bitcoin` will be in your working directory.

If you encounter any problems, contact the Mac OS X makefile's author:
Laszlo Hanyecz (solar@heliacal.net).

Comment: This is the source code, not the binary.

Comment: @MCCCS It's very unlikely a binary is around. See the build instructions I added to UTF-8's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some old releases can be found here: http://satoshi.nakamotoinstitute.org/code/